# Scala implicit conversions and parameters

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to solve an exercise from the book [Scala by example](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf) , *chapter 15 Implicit Parameters and Conver-
sions* which can be found here  :

and have the following code sample :

```
object DemoImplicitConversions {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val xs = List(new Num(1), new Num(4), new Num(2), new Num(6),new Num(3))
    val sortedXs = sort(xs)(num2ordered)
    print(sortedXs.mkString(","))
  }

  type OrderedView[A] = A => Ordered[A]

  // View bound : [A <% Ordered[A]] - means that sort is applicable to lists of type A such that there exists an
  // implicit conversion from A to Ordered[A]

  def sort[A: OrderedView](xs: List[A])(c: OrderedView[A]): List[A] =
    if (xs.isEmpty || xs.tail.isEmpty) xs
    else {
      val (ys, zs) = xs.splitAt(xs.length / 2)
      merge(ys, zs)(c)
    }

  def merge[A: OrderedView](xs: List[A], ys: List[A])(c: OrderedView[A]): List[A] =
    if (xs.isEmpty) ys
    else if (ys.isEmpty) xs
    else if (c(xs.head) < ys.head) xs.head :: merge(xs.tail, ys)(c)
    else ys.head :: merge(xs, ys.tail)(c)

  implicit def num2ordered(x: Num): Ordered[Num] = new Ordered[Num] {
    override def compare(y: Num): Int =
      if (x.value < y.value) -1
      else if (x.value > y.value) 1
      else 0

  }
}

case class Num(value: Int)  {
  override def toString: String = value.toString
}
```

Unfortunately I don't find a way to have implicitly the converter assigned to the method sort so that the client code can look like :

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val xs = List(new Num(1), new Num(4), new Num(2), new Num(6),new Num(3))
    val sortedXs = sort(xs)
    printList(sortedXs)
  }
```

If I add the *implicit* keyword for the converter parameter of the methods merge and sort I get

> ambiguous implicit values

compilation error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type constraint you're placing on `A` is called a *context bound*.  As you correctly write in your comment, `A : OrderedView` means that there is available an implicit value of `A[OrderedView]`.  Your mistake is how you try to get that instance.  You wrote the method signature as:

```
def merge[A: OrderedView](xs: List[A], ys: List[A])(c: OrderedView[A]): List[A]
```

But when using a context bound, it should be:

```
def merge[A: OrderedView](xs: List[A], ys: List[A]): List[A]
```

And then use the `implicitly` operator to get the instance you want.  So your methods could look like:

```
def sort[A: OrderedView](xs: List[A]): List[A] = (merge _).tupled(xs.splitAt(xs.length / 2))

def merge[A: OrderedView](xs: List[A], ys: List[A]): List[A] = {
  //This is how we get the c instance      
  val c = implicitly[OrderedView[A]] 
  ...
}
```

Your other option is to get rid of the context view and use an implicit parameter instead (and then don't use `implicitly` in the method body):

```
def merge[A](xs: List[A], ys: List[A])(implicit c: OrderedView[A]): List[A]
```

These are exactly equivalent.  In fact, the context bound is basically translated into this version during compilation.  What you had was mixing these idioms, by using a context bound *and* using another parameter list (although yours was not implicit, which is required).

In your example, you don't even need an explicit instance of `OrderedView[A]`.  Since it is available in implicit scope (as guaranteed by the context bound), it is automatically applied when necessary.  So, you can even simplify things further:

```
def merge[A: OrderedView](xs: List[A], ys: List[A]): List[A] =
    if (xs.isEmpty) ys
    else if (ys.isEmpty) xs
    //Here, the implicit conversion occurs on xs.head
    else if (xs.head < ys.head) xs.head :: merge(xs.tail, ys)
    else ys.head :: merge(xs, ys.tail)
```

Also, you could use a *view bound* here, instead of the context bound.  Then, you don't even need to introduce the `OrderedView` type alias:

```
def sort[A <% Ordered[A]](xs: List[A]): List[A]
def merge[A <% Ordered[A]](xs: List[A], ys: List[A]): List[A]
//Or, equivalently:
def sort[A](xs: List[A])(implicit ev: A => Ordered[A]): List[A]
def merge[A](xs: List[A], ys: List[A])(implicit ev: A => Ordered[A]): List[A]
```

Read more about context bounds (and view bounds) [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html).

As an unrelated note, you should also explore using `match` statements, which are pretty powerful in Scala:

```
def merge[A <% Ordered[A]](xs: List[A], ys: List[A]): List[A] = (xs, ys) match {
      case (Nil, _) => ys
      case (_, Nil) => xs
      case (xhd::xtl, yhd::ytl) if xhd < yhd => xhd :: merge(xtl, ys)
      case (_, yhd::ytl) => yhd :: merge(xs, ytl)
}
```

Comment: `implicitly` is not necessary here. All uses of `c` can simply be removed, i.e. `else if (xs.head < ys.head) xs.head :: merge(xs.tail, ys)`

Answer (score 1):

This definition:

```
def sort[A: OrderedView](xs: List[A])(c: OrderedView[A]): List[A]
```

is in fact equivalent to this:

```
def sort[A](xs: List[A])(c: OrderedView[A])(implicit ev: OrderedView[A]): List[A]
```

That is, your `c: OrderedView[A]` parameter is absolutely independent on the context bound, it is just another parameter.

You just need either to omit the context bound:

```
def sort[A](xs: List[A])(implicit c: OrderedView[A]): List[A]
```

or omit the parameter:

```
def sort[A: OrderedView](xs: List[A]): List[A]
```

In the latter case, however, if you want to access the implicit parameter you will have to do it with `implicitly`:

```
implicitly[OrderedView[A]](xs.head)
```

Maybe you won't even need to call it explicitly as an implicit conversion will fire automatically.